# Можно ли на QFrame положить QBrush?

Tags: qt

```
 QBrush brush;
 brush.setStyle(Qt::LinearGradientPattern);
 ui->frame->setStyle(brush); // !!ошибка !! не во можно преобразовать QBrush v QStyle
```

Comment: Это чтобы раскрасить задний фон?

Comment: @gil9red да, покрасить в иной цвет я знаю а как сделать градиент нет.

Comment: А, так, через StyleSheet пробовали?

Comment: @gil9red     ui->frame->styleSheet(Qt::LinearGradientPattern);
// 2660

Comment: не, там setStyleSheet, который принимает строку. Синтаксис Style Sheet повторяет CSS, и есть примеры указания заднего фона виджета в виде градиента. Погуглите: `qt style sheet background gradient`